# How to disable Safari's Frequently Visited blacklist on macOS?

Tags: safari, catalina

I'm pretty sure Safari on macOS has some sort of blacklisting mechanism that's preventing some of the my frequently visited websites from appearing in that list. Is there a way to disable that feature?

I have Safari 13.0.4 on macOS Catalina but I think the feature (issue) has been present perhaps for years.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether there is a blacklisting mechanism.

I think that if you ever delete a site from the frequently visited window, then it'll never appear again:
Check `BannedURLStrings` in `~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist` with

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c print ~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error Reading File`, also `cat ~/Library/Safari/TopSites.plist` gives me `Operation not permitted`. I tried both with the Safari app open and also closed.

Comment: Using `sudo` with those commands doesn't work either.

Comment: @rraallvv, see https://www.howtogeek.com/443611/how-macos-catalinas-new-security-features-work/ for instance

Comment: Terminal is not asking for permissions when I try to access the folder `~/Library/Safari` nor its contents, please see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/GJtiCfq.png) with the options that appear on Files and Folders. Also I'm not able to add more entries because the +/- button is disabled.

Comment: @rraallvv, apparently, you need to give Full Disk Access to Terminal. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8637915

Comment: The websites in TopSites.plist are not exactly the same that appear on Safari under "Frequently Visited" although the file does contain the one that I thought that was blacklisted.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, the list `TopSites` in the file has 12 entries and one of those is the "blacklisted" website. Also the websites listed are not exactly the same that appear on Safari. The websites listed in `BannedURLStrings` look like `http://www.localhost:8080` and none of those is the "blacklisted" website.

Comment: @rraallvv, then I don't know what can be wrong. It was worth a try.