# Safari's frequently visited sites: showing never visited sites, which appear again and again after deletion

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I dislike the frequently visited sites feature when I can't purge a site I feel shouldn't have space in the list.

There is a shop's web site I visited once. Now this shop continues to be listed as a frequently visited site in Safari, despite the visit from a long time ago. Next, I deleted this site from the frequently visited proposals, but it appears again and again. Seems like it is a "paid ad".

I do not want to disable the whole feature, but I want veto control when a site worms it's way in.

Is there a way to clear this and start new or otherwise surgically remove one pesky "not-frequently visited" site?

Comment: Are there any other devices with Safari and your iCloud? Seldomly used iPhone or iPad or macOS systems? I believe this data is cloud aggregated from all devices to try and show a unified view. It's a hunch that this isn't a straight bug and instead some other device needs the "cut" command to excise this one persistent page.

Comment: If you had a Mac, you [could inspect the preference where deleted items are stored](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/405641/5472).